# select one row from list that has same ids

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table, `documentfilename`, with data like following

```
requestid | document_no | docfilename
1               1           space
2               123         space
2               124         mytestfile.pdf  
3               555         space 
3               556         space
```

I would like to be able to select data so that it will look like

```
requestid | document_no | docfilename
1               1           space
2               124         mytestfile.pdf  
3               555         space
```

My own query produces the following

```
requestid | document_no | docfilename
1               1           space
2               123         space
2               124         mytestfile.pdf  
3               555         space
```

Comment: I don't understand the pattern – please, elaborate better. And post your current query.

Comment: In particular, explain why `2, 123, "space"` is worse than `2, 124, "mytestfile.pdf"`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What *is* your current query? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: what should be the expected result if you have for example: 1 1 space/ 2 122 space/ 2 123 space_ext/ 2 124 mytestfile.pdf/ 3 555 space/ 3 556 space ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT df1.request_id, df1.document_no, df1.docfilename
  FROM documentfilename df1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT request_id, MAX(document_no) AS document_no
      FROM documentfilename
  ) df2 ON df1.request_id = df2.request_id
       AND df1.document_no = df2.document_no
```

Comment: Although I see now that you don't want the `MAX(document_no)` ... or the `MIN()`

Comment: This query will not return the result of the row including document_no `555` it'll return for `556` which is not wanted

Comment: True - hence my comment